# What USB-C Footprint is this?

Tags: usb, connector, footprint, usb-c

I have to replace a USB-C connector. After desoldering I found a rather uncommon footprint. Has anyone seen this footprint before and knows where to find a new connector of this type?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It could be a footprint that is compatible with 2 parts.

Comment: It's rather close to a reference design of the [USB Type-C Specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf) -- see figure 3-6 on page 51.

Comment: It looks like one pad is missing.

Comment: This is a classic "combo" footptint, part through-hole, partly surface mount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome at EE.SE
An example for such a connector can be found here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/assmann-wsw-components/AUSB1-DFN-PTR3/5810164
The footprint is just a practical combination of smd and tht to use the board-space in a more efficient way.

I wish you luck with whatever you want to achieve with this board :)

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly the one I was looking for!

Comment: You can say "use the board in more efficient way", or better "to accomodate low-cost low-resolution cheaper PCB manufacturing".